# ebook renamer Application in Linux

Tags: ebooks

Bulk **rename** of ebook files (epub,mobi,pdf) using embedded meta-data *(title, author(s)).*

Any One **Tools** .... Linux Help you.

Comment: You can use Calibre and then search for the books metadata using regex.There's a [discussion about that in reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Calibre/comments/gj8ltj/plugin_to_mass_rename_books_by_removing/).

Comment: Also take a look at [this](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/edit.html).

Comment: thank you Above two comment  i am Try